# javascript looking for ways to block users ability to copy and paste text

Tags: javascript, copy-paste

My client has a single page app where we are adding a new module. they want to show the user a preview of some content. They then want to have the user click on a button which will post the content on behalf of the user to their defined social network account. The code we post will have a tracking URL. I though of using a clear div over the preview content, but am looking for ways where I can block copy and paste options with the preview.

Any thoughts? I found older posts but wanted to make sure I was using the latest js options to do it.

thanks

Jeff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

override all the mouse and keyboard event using java script